# Does Virtual Families continue while it's closed?

Tags: virtual-families

How exactly does [Virtual Families](http://www.virtualfamilies.com/) work? For example, if I turn off my laptop, will it continue to progress? I've read that even if I exit the game, their lives still continue unless I specifically pause it. Can anyone explain this to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy/pasted from http://jayisgames.com/archives/2009/04/virtual_families.php

> Just like Virtual Villagers, Virtual Families continues to run even when the game isn't open. It is an important aspect of gameplay, since your family will continue to evolve, even when you are not around. As long as they have food your family can survive a couple of days without interaction, but if you're not going to be able to play for a couple of weeks, you may want to go in and pause the game before quitting. You don't want to come back to a house full of skeletons, do you?

Comment: Can you explain how that works? I mean, when I exit Virtual Families and check the processes, it's not there anymore. So how can they continue to run? I'm not connected to the internet either when I'm playing so that crosses out the option of having a persistent server connection.

Comment: I don't own the game so I haven't got any first hand experience but my best guess would be that when you start the game it looks at the current system time and calculates events from the last time you closed the game. If you are adventurous you could try closing the game, change system time to some time in the future and open the game again.

Comment: [This site](http://www.playfirst.com/tips/virtual-families/12600/how-do-you-speed-up-time) confirms my theory of the system clock being used for calculations...